# In sentences like "if they had known you were here", does "were" refer to the past or present?

Tags: meaning, irrealis-mood

1. What a row would there have been if they had known you **were** here!
2. How great would have been her disappointment if she had known what they **had** actually thought!
   (Both are example sentences from *The Cambridge grammar of the English language*, without context)

In (1), how do you interpret "were"？ Does the sentence imply you are here now or is it talking about a past situation?
In (2), does "had" indicate "thought" is anterior to her knowing or to the time of utterance.

I think the two questions are related, so I ask them in the same thread.

Comment: Both are confusing because of "*irrealis mood*", more commonly known as *unreal grammar*". Are you familiar with it?

Comment: @gotube  Yes, I'm familiar with irrealis.  That is part of the reason why I asked, actually.

Comment: (1) seems to refer to a past situation - otherwise it would be "What a row would there be if they knew you were here!"

Comment: @KateBunting  Thanks. And what do you think is the most salient interpretation for the second sentence?

Comment: (2) is a rather strange sentence to me, which is why I didn't post a formal answer. I think it  means that the thinking was prior to her (not) knowing about it.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you mean the word order in the first half of the sentence is strange？

Comment: The mode of expression is stiff and old-fashioned - today we would say _How disappointed she would have been._ It looks like a literary quotation , but I can't find it with Google Ngrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are *ambiguous* -- both interpretations are possible.

In the first, if the person is still there, then there's a choice between "are/were" since backshifting is optional in situations where the verb is still true now. And if the person is not still there, then "were" is required. So either situation could be true with "were".

The same logic applies to the second situation.

Comment: A follow up question.   "would there have been"  can only refer to a specific time in the past.  It can't refer to **a period of time leading up to the present** in this context.  Do I get it right?

Comment: I believe you're right. I can't think of a way "would have been" can ever refer to something in the present, even though it's unreal.